# Dell Inspiron 1545 wireless not detecting certain networks

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, dell, inspiron

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 having just reinstalled to see if it fixed the problem, I have installed the wireless drivers and they appear to be functioning as I am picking up the WiFi in the hotel down the road! It is not however, detecting the wireless router nor the booster in our house (and I'm next to the booster connected via cable just to type this out!)

I'm running out of ideas, I've updated the headers and it won't reinstall the driver. I just can't fathom why it wont pick up those networks as the other 4 computers in the house can - main difference being they are all running Windows 7/8

Comment: Does the laptop have windows installed? does it pick them up in windows? Could it be a wireless G only card maybe and router is running N or better?

Answer (score 0):

once , I had this problem with my old laptop Dell inspiron 15XX (I don't remember exactly) and it worked

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source

sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```